Proving Various Identities Related to the Fibonacci Sequence
Let $a_{1} = a_{2} = 1, a_{3} = 2$$, and $$ a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 3$.
The sequence $(a_{n})$ is known as the Fibonacci sequence. Prove that:
(i)$a_{1} + a_{2} + \ldots + a_{n} = a_{n+2} - 1$
(ii)$a_{1} + a_{3} + a_{5} + \ldots + a_{2n-1} = a_{2n}$
(iii)$a_{2} + a_{4} + a_{6} + \ldots + a_{2n} = a_{2n+1} - 1$
(iv)$a_{n+1}^{2} = a_{n} \cdot a_{n+2} + (-1)^{n}$
(v)$a_{1} \cdot a_{2} + a_{2} \cdot a_{3} + \ldots + a_{2n-1} \cdot a_{2n} = (a_{2n})^{2}$.
(vi) $\quad a_{1} \cdot a_{2} + a_{2} \cdot a_{3} + \ldots + a_{2n} \cdot a_{2n+1} = \left(a_{2n+1}\right)^{2} - 1.$
This is the exact question I copied from my textbook, which has to be proved by induction.
I wondered how can be proved using induction, I tried assuming $n = k$,
And then $S_{k+1}$. But couldn't get further in any of the problem in
These aren't so many questions they are interrelated.
Source - Challenge and thrill of pre-college mathematics.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Ok I am deleting this question now and edit it carefully and then post it

No, don’t post a new question, just edit this question, click the edit button in this question.

Is there a direct way to convert this into mathjax notation

is this question from challenge and thrill of precollege mathematics? If not please post the source

@ShresthJain Welccome to the site. Use $ around inline formulas and $$ around block formulas. But note that everything should be in the links provided by José Carlos Santos, so please look up those first if you need more guidance.

@AarushSaharan Yes It is from that book

Actually you do not need to prove all six statements through inductions, as some can be derived by past results, for example (i) + (ii)$\implies$(iii) , while the tricks in proving these identities usually rely on the property of Fibonacci numbers, by comparing the goal of your question, and the items you have right now (sometimes the strong form of induction may even needed). Here I may show you one as example (Here I pick (v)).
Let $P(n)$ be proposition (v). Then we have $P(1)$ is true as $a_1a_2=1=(a_2)^2$. Assume $P(k)$ is true for some positive integer $k$. Consider $P(k+1)$, by induction assumption, we have $$\sum{a_ia_{i+1}}=(a_{2k})^2+(a_{2k}a_{2k+1}+a_{2k+1}a_{2k+2})$$
Therefore, we can claim that \begin{align*}(a_{2k})^2+(a_{2k}a_{2k+1}+a_{2k+1}a_{2k+2})=(a_{2k+2})^2&\iff a_{2k}a_{2k+1}+a_{2k+1}a_{2k+2}=(a_{2k+2})^2-(a_{2k})^2\\&\iff a_{2k+1}(a_{2k}+a_{2k+2})=(a_{2k+2}-a_{2k})(a_{2k+2}+a_{2k})\\
&\iff a_{2k+1}=a_{2k+2}-a_{2k}\end{align*}
While the last line is true by the definition of Fibonacci sequences. So by induction the result followes.
Of course, induction is not the only way, for example (i) can be proved by telescoping sum, but if you want to use induction, you need to know your goal.
